# bash: exit if grep pipeline selects any lines

Tags: bash, grep

I want a grep pipeline to succeed if *no* lines are selected:

```
set -o errexit
echo foo | grep -v foo
# no output, pipeline returns 1, shell exits
! echo foo | grep -v foo
# no output, pipeline returns 1 reversed by !, shell continues
```

Similarly, I want the pipeline to fail (and the enclosing shell to exit, when `errexit` is set) if any lines come out the end. The above approach does not work:

```
echo foo | grep -v bar
# output, pipeline returns 0, shell continues
! echo foo | grep -v bar
# output, ???, shell continues
! (echo foo | grep -v bar)
# output, ???, shell continues
```

I finally found a method, but it seems ugly, and I'm looking for a better way.

```
echo foo | grep -v bar | (! grep '.*')
# output, pipeline returns 1, shell exits
```

Any explanation of the behavior above would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Aside: `errexit` often behaves in surprising ways, to the point that many regulars of the Freenode #bash channel advise against its use (probably something like a 50/50 split; consensus isn't overwhelming in either direction). See BashFAQ #105: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Comment: If my answer needs additions to fully address your question, could you speak to what those are?

Answer (score 4):

`set -e`, aka `set -o errexit`, only handles *unchecked* commands; its intent is to prevent errors from going unnoticed, not to be an explicit flow control mechanism. It makes sense to check explicitly here, since it's a case you actively care about as opposed to an error that could happen as a surprise.

```
echo foo | grep -v bar && exit
```

More to the point, several of your commands make it explicit that you care about (and thus are presumably already manually handling) exit status -- thus setting the "checked" flag, making `errexit` have no effect.

---

Running `! pipeline`, in particular, sets the `checked` flag for the pipeline -- it means that you're explicitly doing something with its exit status, thus implying that automatic failure-case handling need not apply.

Comment: Plus one since what you are saying is definitely right. Do you think that there is a way without using grep's -v option? I've scratched my head but ended up suggesting `if` (which is even still the most readable solution IMHO) .. But do you see a way without `-v` and without `if`?

Comment: @hek2mgl, since the question is whether *any* lines would be returned without `grep -v`, using `! grep` would give a different result -- indicating whether *all* lines fail to match, as opposed to whether *any* lines fail to match.

Comment: @hek2mgl, ...that said, if the question is just how negate the test, changing `&&` to `||` would do.

Comment: ...also, since there's no `>/dev/null` or `-q` flag on the grep, side effects (content printed to stdout) presumably matter. If the user didn't want anything printed, adding `-q` would be the efficient approach -- that way grep can exit immediately as soon as it proves that at least one match exists.

Comment: No, `||` would not do since you wouldn't be able to differentiate between different results of grep. It would simply fail in that case, even if grep won't find any lines

Comment: True, that removes the ability to distinguish between lack-of-matches or unrelated-failures, but often that's good enough. `grep ...; (( $? == 1 )) || ...` is an available approach if the exact exit status matters.

Comment: Btw, `||` was my first suggestion but then I've realized the above issue. It's sometimes nice to scratch the head about such *simple* things .. :) Let me up-vote the question.. It is good

Answer (score 1):

This is not a one-liner, but it works:

```
if echo foo | grep foo ; then
    exit 1
fi
```

Meaning the shell exits with 1 if grep finds something. Also I don't think that `set -e` or `set -o errexit` should be used for logic, it should be used for what it is meant for, for stopping your script if an unexpected error occurs.